# How do I prove that $T(x)=Ax$ is an isomorphism between $\text{im}(A^T)$ and $\text{im}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

This is my proof: 
I think that I need to prove that the linear transformation is both injective and surjective. For this I am doing the following:

$ker(A^T) = im(A)$ $ perpendicular$
Therefore this transformation is surjective.
To prove that this is injective:
we know that for a linear transformation to be injective, it must be one-to-one. Since U is the image of the transpose of A, it must be one-to-one because you are not adding any extra columns are rows to the final transformation. Therefore, you can't have any extra elements.

Am I doing this right? Is my "proof" even remotely close to right?

Comment: Notice that, once the ranks of $A^T$ and of $A$ are equal, $\text{dim}\,U=\text{dim}\,V$. So, you only need to prove that $T$ is injective (resp. surjective) and by the rank-nullity theorem it will follow that $T$ is surjective (resp. injective).

Comment: I don't get either of your proofs.

Comment: Hint: $\text{ker}(AA^T)=\text{ker}(A^T)$.

Comment: Note that *injective* and *one to one* are synonyms. When you write "we know that for a linear transformation to be injective, it must be one-to-one," this is like writing "for a linear transformation to be injective, it must be injective."

Answer (score 2):

Your proofs make little sense.

As Larara says in a comment, you should begin by noting that $U=\text{im}(A^T)$ and $V=\text{im}(A)$ have the same dimension. (That's because the row rank and the column rank of $A$ are the same.) Therefore, to prove that $T$ is an isomorphism, you simply need to show it is injective.

To show $T$ is injective, you need to show that if $T(u_1)=T(u_2)$, then $u_1=u_2$. But note that every element of $U$ has the form $A^Tv$ for some $v$.

Because $T(u)=Au$ and $u=A^Tv$, this means you need to show that if $AA^Tv=AA^Tw$, then $A^Tv=A^Tw$. In other words, you need to show $AA^Tx=0$ implies $A^Tx=0$. This is the harder half of the proof that $\text{ker}(AA^T)=\text{ker}(A^T)$.

The trick is to use the dot product. If $A\color{blue}{A^Tx}=0$, then multiplying both sides by $x^T$ gives $\color{red}{x^TA}\color{blue}{A^Tx}=x^T0=0$. But $\color{red}{x^TA}=(\color{blue}{A^Tx})^T$, so this says $$(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)=\|A^Tx\|^2=0$$
Hence $A^Tx=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some additional conceptual insights to be gained by proving this result WITHOUT using the fact that $rank(A) = rank(A^T)$. In fact, once the isomorphism result is established independently, it will immediately imply $rank(A) = rank(A^T)$, thereby yielding a conceptual proof of the latter.

We can establish isomorphism without assuming $rank(A) = rank(A^T)$ using basic properties of orthogonality and orthocomplementary subspaces. Let us assume that the entries in $A$ are real numbers (it will work on the complex field as well) so $\mbox{im}(A^T)$ and $\mbox{im}(A)$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively. We will need to prove that $T(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$ is one-one and onto.

To prove that $T$ is onto, we will need to show that for any $\vec{y} \in \mbox{im}(A)$, there exists $\vec{x} \in \mbox{im}(A^T)$ such that $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}$. Since $\vec{y} \in \mbox{im}(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, there exists $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vec{y} = A\vec{u}$. We can write $\vec{u} = A^{T}\vec{z} + \vec{w}$ for some $\vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and some $\vec{w} \in \mbox{im}(A^{T})^{\perp}$ making use of the orthogonal direct sum decomposition: $\mathbb{R}^n = \mbox{im}(A^{T}) \oplus \mbox{im}(A^{T})^{\perp}$ (note that $A^{T}\vec{z} \in \mbox{im}(A^T)$). Therefore, $\vec{y} = A\vec{u} = AA^{T}\vec{z} + A\vec{w}$. Furthermore, since $\vec{w} \in \mbox{im}(A^{T})^{\perp}$, it follows that $\vec{w}$ is orthogonal to each of the columns of $A^T$ or the rows of $A$ implying $A\vec{w} = \vec{0}$. This yields $\vec{y} = AA^{T}\vec{z} = A\vec{x}$, where $\vec{x} = A^T\vec{z} \in \mbox{im}(A^T)$. This proves that $T$ is onto.

That $T$ is one-one has been neatly proved in the earlier post by @symplectomorphic, but I include a slightly different presentation here for completeness. Suppose we are given that $T(\vec{x}_1) = T(\vec{x}_2)$ for $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ in $\mbox{im}(A^T)$. Let $\vec{u} = \vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_2$ so $A\vec{u} = \vec{0}$. This means that $\vec{u}$ is orthogonal to the rows of $A$ (or columns of $A^T$) and, hence, to vectors in the linear span of columns of $A^T$. Therefore, $\vec{u} \in \mbox{im}(A^T)^{\perp}$. On the other hand, $\vec{u}$ itself resides in $\mbox{im}(A^T)$ because $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ are vectors in $\mbox{im}(A^T)$. Hence, $\vec{u}$ is orthogonal to itself, which means that $\vec{u} = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{x}_1 = \vec{x}_2$. Therefore, $T$ is one-one.

This completes the proof that $T$ is an isomorphism. One can easily deduce $rank(A) = rank(A^T)$ as a corollary of the above because isomorphic subspaces have the same dimension. In fact, they will carry any basis of its domain to a basis of its range. See this post:

The Pointer (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/356308/the-pointer), Proof that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ carries a basis to a basis., URL (version: 2017-11-15): [Proof that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ carries a basis to a basis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521291)